What was the Order of the Phoenix doing in the time it took for Harry and co. to get from Hogwarts to the Ministry
What I don't understand is, is that it must have taken Harry and his friends hours to get from Hogwarts, which is in Scotland, to London, on the back of thestrals. It must have taken them at least 3 hours, why wasn't an Order member stationed outside the Ministry to head them off? They weren't guarding the Prophecy, and I bet Snape wasn't waiting hours to go "Oh they didn't come back from the forest, now let's go tell the Order." It doesn't make any sense. What was the Order doing in the meantime? The only semi-reasonable explanations involve thestrals being unbelievably fast.

"The only semi-reasonable explanations involve thestrals being unbelievably fast." Any reason to rule that out as the explanation? They are magic after all.

Threstals are very fast even if we don't consider magic. Scotland is around 615 km away from London. Moving at 1200 km per hour takes around 30 minutes. Less than the speed of sound so that Snape wouldn't be alerted. At that speed, Harry and everyone else wouldn't have fared so well. There must be magic somewhere in here.
